# How to save processed data to text file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-io

I'm using **JavaScript** for a project.

1. scan data from text file
2. process it
3. store back the processed data into text file

I have the data retrieval part working but I'm not able to store processed data through JavaScript.

*I'm gathering the processed data into an array...*

Is there any API available?

Comment: You doing this in the browser or what?

Comment: It's hard to help you if we can't see your code.

Comment: @Jordan Not necessarily. If he just has a string he wants to save that's fine...

Comment: And if you are doing this in the browser, where do you want the text file to be? On the server?

Comment: @ChristianStewart If he had posted his code we wouldn't be waiting for him to update his question or post a reply before we can help him. :)

Comment: Its more of a export thing, like saving settings to local computer.

Comment: Yes, I m running this in my browser. The text file is stored on the server, output file gets downloaded.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **You could use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).**

*I have a **sample array** as follows...*

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "GMC", "Ford", "Honda"];
```

*And I **write to text file** as such...*

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.createWriteStream('cars.txt');
file.on('error', function(err) { /* error handling */ });
cars.forEach(function(v) { file.write(v.join(', ') + '\n'); });
file.end();
```